# Ingress affinity session max age

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, sticky-session

I am using ingress affinity session in order to keep communication between a client and a pod. Because sticky session could cause some overloading to a pod (the clients keep same pod).

I'm looking for best practices about the parameter [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/).

The example value is 172 800 (second) which mean 48 hours.
Why? It's a huge duration, is it possible to set up it to 30 minutes?
By the way, what happens when the application session has expired? Does the ingress rebalance the client or keep the same pod?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud provider?

Comment: Did you try to change the values of session-cookie-expires and session-cookie-max-age?